# How to count curly brackets in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to find a way to count how many curly brackets in any string.

For example:

```
Dear {0}, Your one time password is {1} Thanks
```

I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/matchstick but it does not work as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var count = ("Dear {0}, Your one time password is {1} Thanks".match(/{|}/g) || []).length;
```

Hope it helps.